# Serializing object with java

Tags: java, serialization, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

I am trying to serialize an object with ObjectOutputStream and FileOutputStream, however an error with the class name is being shown.

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
 NewClientClass AddClient = new NewClientClass(IDNumber.getText(), FirstName.getText(), LastName.getText(), Address.getText(), DateOfBirth.getText(), Profession.getText());
       try {   
        int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile()));
            out.writeObject(AddClient); //the application crashes.
            out.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Saved");
        }
```

As you can see I am declaring a new client and getting the data from the text boxes. The data is stored correctly as I checked tru debugging, the only problem is when writing the object to file.

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: Does your object implement java.io.Serializable? Post the error message please.

Comment: what error do you get (Stacktrace)?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy check comments in code

Comment: @Burkhard no not using that import

Comment: **What** 'error with the class name is being shown'?

Answer (score 1):

Without further details, the most likely culprit is that lack of the implementation of the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface from `NewClientClass`:

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the
>   java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this
>   interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.
>   All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable. The
>   serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to
>   identify the semantics of being serializable.

EDIT:

Assuming you have something like so:

```
public class NewClientClass
{
    public NewClientClass (String idNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String address, String dateOfBirth, String profession)
    {
         ...
    }

}
```

You would just need to make it like so:

```
public class NewClientClass implements Serializable
{
    public NewClientClass (String idNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String address, String dateOfBirth, String profession)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

That should be all you need to do (do not forget to import the package containing that interface). The `Serializable` interface will *mark* your class for seriliazation.

Again, you did not mention what exception you are getting, so this is purely speculative.

Comment: where do I have to edit please in the NewClientClass ?

Comment: @NeilGambin: I have modified my answer. I hope it solves your problem.